# Visual Studio C#: Recognize whether Workspace was created

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, workspace

Now im working on **Client-Side** with:

```
Workstation.Current.ReloadCache();

var ws = Workstation.Current.GetAllLocalWorkspaceInfo().ToList();
```

to see whether new workspaces were created with VS or with any other application.

But is there a way to hang on tfs or something to get an event like 'WorkspaceCreated'?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know whether the workspace was created on client-side. You don't have to hook up the events from TFS.`TfsConfigurationServer` and `IEventService` has to do with the eventing server in TFS, not the events in the client object model. So you can't get the "WorkspaceCreated" event info from TFS server.

You can call [QueryWorkspaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138991.aspx)

```
workspace = versionControl.QueryWorkspaces(
                     workspaceName, 
                     versionControl.AuthorizedUser, 
                     Environment.MachineName).SingleOrDefault();
```

The code above will **query for the workspace for a user on the computer this code runs.** If the collection is empty it will return null in workspace or it will return the single item in the list.   More detail info, please refer this link: [C# Code to check whether the workspace exist on TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749968/c-sharp-code-to-check-whether-the-workspace-exist-on-tfs)

Comment: Sorry, I mean i want to hook up at client side.

I read about TfsConfigurationServer and IEventService but thats not working for me because there is not service running for this....

Answer (score 0):

The workspace is created on your local machine. There isn't any event occur on server side. So there isn't any way to do this.